# Using VMware/Virtual box to simulate a cluster of nodes, but actually using a single machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I am developing a webapp using Cassandra database which works on a multi-nodes cluster. But I don't have multiple machines to create a cluster while development. How do I create a cluster using the resources of a single machine? Can I do this by creating VMware or Virtual box instances that are connected to each other to form cluster?

Comment: The answer tells you that what you had planned to do will indeed work. What might be more useful is information regarding the availability of a virtual cluster, preconfigured and preloaded with software such as MPI or GASNet, say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If the computer can handle it, you can run multiple virtual machines simultaneously. The easiest configuration would be to have them all use **bridged** network adapters, so they are on the same subnet as the host.

Comment: VMware player, VirtualBox, it doesn't matter.